# Why is one of these Eloquent Javascript Chessboard solutions better than the other

Tags: javascript

I took on the Chessboard puzzle from the book Eloquent Javascript and devised the following solution without looking at hints

```
var newline = "\n";
var counter = .5;
var string1 = " # # # #";
var string2 = "# # # # ";
while (counter <= 3.5){
  console.log(string1 + newline);
  console.log(string2 + newline);
  counter++
}
```

I originally had too many lines written out so simply changed my counter to 'half steps'.
Looking up how others accomplished this, I found this solution.

```
    var size = 8;
for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  var line = "";
  for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    var total = i + j;
    if (total % 2 == 0) { 
      line += '#';
    } else {
      line += ' ';
    }
  }
  console.log(line);
}
```

Can you explain why one version may be better than the other? Also, a plain-english explanation of the second would be helpful. I talked myself into a headache trying to comment it plainly.

Comment: I like the first since you can get a sense of what it's doing at a glance.  The latter builds up the same results strings but in a super complex manner. I so prefer the fist!

Comment: "I talked myself into a headache trying to comment it plainly." That is already a strong indication that the other version is better.

Comment: Maybe a better fit for the Code Review Stackexchange.

Comment: One thing I see may be viewed as useful in the second one is that you can change the size of the square board simply by changing the var size.  Obviously if you're strictly making a chessboard then changing the size of it is kind of unnecessary, but imagine your job was to make a 64 x 64 chessboard, in the first one that would be two ugly strings to write out, with much potential for error, in the second you would just change var size = 64

Comment: @Thilo [codereview.se] is NOT for seeking explanations of code written by other people, which is primarily what this question appears to be.

Comment: @z416175 I do see how the `size` var _squares_ the size of the board and thought that was useful.

As a beginner I want to make sure I understand the reasoning, and can read/step through the code.

Comment: just imagine having to write out `string1` and `string2` for a 64 x 64 version of a chess board for whatever reason. would be a nightmare.  the second one is reusable, in that no matter what size board you need, as long as its square, it will work.  you could make a 1000 x 1000 board if you so desired, with one simple change. and even if you didnt want a square board, would just be an additional minor adjustment, as opposed to having to edit two different strings each time you wanted to change the size of the board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain english explanation of second one - the `var size = 8` will be the size of the board.  The first for loop declares the `var line` and eventually logs it to console.  It will log to console for every line, or row, if you prefer.

The second for loop will actually build the line, or row, adding to `var line` for each column in the row.  Instead of having to declare two strings like you did in the first version, it knows how each row should end up looking based on some variables and a rule.  The rule is if `total` is divisible by 2, then add a "#", and if not, then add a " ".  `total` is calculated by adding `i` and `j`.

So in the first row `i` is always 0, and `j` will be 0, then 1, then 2, etc...so `total` be divisible by 2, then not divisible by 2, then divisible by 2, etc...then in the second row `i` will be equal to 1, and `j` again will be 0, then 1, then 2, etc..so now `total` will first not de divisible by 2, then divisible by 2, then not, etc...for the third row, `i` will be 2, which will basically act as `i` being 0 since both 0 and 2 leave no remainder when divided by 2.  This is how the second for loop accomplishes the same thing as your `string1` and `string2`.  I'm sorry this is a bit wordy, hope it makes sense...I'll put some comments in the actual code below.

```
// sets size of board, since the first loop will run for this amount of
// times, and log a row to console each time, and the second loop will add   
// this many characters to the string to be logged.
var size = 8;

// first loop, which will run a number of times equal to the size
// variable, and log a row to console each time
for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {

  // declares the string to be logged as the row
  var line = "";

  // this loop will run a number of times equal to the size
  // variable, and add a character to the line variable each time,
  // either a "#" or a " "
  for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {

    // the total variable will be used to determine if the character added
    // to the line is a "#" or a " "
    // basically, any time i is 0 or divisible by 2, the row will
    // begin with a "#" and alternate from there as j changes, 
    // if i is not divisible by 2, the row will begin with a " " 
    // and alternate from there
    var total = i + j;

    // this if else statement actually uses total to added either "#" or " "
    if (total % 2 == 0) { 
      line += '#';
    } else {
      line += ' ';
    }
  }

  // this is outside of the second loop, and now the line variable is done
  // being added to, and the line is logged
  console.log(line);
}
```